# How to downgrade kernel version in Openwrt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, openwrt

I am completely new in kernel upgrade/downgrade process in Linux . I downloaded a `openwrt` VMware OS . I can see the kernel version by `uname -r` . I am getting `3.10.49` . Now i want to downgrade the kernel to `3.10.36` . How can i do this ? Should i download source file ?

I can see the source file from GitHub : https://github.com/respeaker/openwrt/tree/master

I am completely new in this process . Any help ?

Comment: Why do you need that?! Especially taking into consideration that you are talking about stable releases.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already downloaded the code then I don't think you need to download the code again. You can use the existing features of `git` to switch b/w the kernel version or branch as well.

You can list all the tags binding through `git tag -l`. Then you can switch to your particular kernel version or branch through the `checkout` command like: `git checkout tags/v4.7-rc7` (replace `v4.7-rc7` with your required kernel version)